# Blue Dot Menu MVC - Use Server Control in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, intuit-partner-platform

I am using an MVC app to integrate Intuit Anywhere and an MVC app. I see there is a server control for the blue dot menu:

```
            <!-- Blue Dot Menu -->
            <div runat="server" id="blueDotDiv">
                <ipp:bluedot></ipp:bluedot>
            </div>
```

How do I integrate this server control inside of an MVC site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Azure MVC Web Role template that you can use as a reference:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0300_Windows_Azure_Program_for_Intuit_Anywhere/0003_Intuit_Anywhere_Azure_Web_Role_Templates

The div that wraps the Blue Dot menu in the ASP.NET WebForms sample project is used to control its visibility on the server side (hidden when user is connected), but you can implement hiding the control any way you want.

When the button is clicked, it calls the server side resource you have specified in the intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup javascript function, which in turn calls the AppMenu API to retrieve the content of the menu:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Add_the_Connect_Button

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference/0010_AppMenu_API

Comment: New links are here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0300_windows_azure_program_for_quickbooksapi/0001_installing_the_windows_azure_sdk_2.0_for_quickbooksapi and https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app    https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/0010_appmenu_api